# How to fix the error in codeigniter project?

Tags: php, codeigniter

My error message in codeigniter framework:
    A Database Error Occurred

```
Error Number: 1140

In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'hms.rooms.id'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

SELECT `rooms`.*, count(room_no) as total_rooms FROM `rooms` WHERE `room_type_id` = '10'

Filename: D:/Installed_Apps/OpenServer/OpenServer/domains/hms.loc/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691
```

Why is there such an error and how to eliminate it? In what there can be a problem in the code?

In these functions, something is wrong or everything is normal?

function check_availability($check_in,$check_out,$adults,$kids,$room_type_id){
                    $query      =   '?date_from='.$check_in.'&date_to='.$check_out.'&adults='.$adults.'&kids='.$kids.'&room_type='; 
                    $CI =& get_instance();
                    if($check_in==$check_out){
                        $check_out  =   date('Y-m-d', strtotime($check_out.'+ 1 day'));
                    }

```
                                            $CI->db->where('id',1);
                    $settings   =   $CI->db->get('settings')->row_array();

                                        $CI->db->where('id',$room_type_id);
                                        $CI->db->select('room_types.*,base_price as price');
                    $room_type  =   $CI->db->get('room_types')->row_array();
                    //echo '<pre>'; print_r($room_type);die;

                                        $CI->db->where('room_type_id',$room_type_id);
                                        $CI->db->select('rooms.*,count(room_no) as total_rooms');
                    $rooms      =   $CI->db->get('rooms')->row_array();
                    $total_rooms    =   $rooms['total_rooms'];
                    //echo '<pre>'; print_r($rooms);die;
                    $begin = new DateTime($check_in);
                    $end = new DateTime($check_out);

                    $interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day');
                    $period = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end);

                    foreach($period as $dt){
                        $date       =    $dt->format( "Y-m-d" );    
                        $dayno      =    $dt->format( "N" );
                        $day        =    $dt->format( "D" );
                        $day        =   strtolower($day);
                        ///echo $date;die;          
                        //check for room block period

                        if($date >= $settings['room_block_start_date'] && $date <=$settings['room_block_end_date'])
                        {
                            $block_message  =   "Sorry.. No Room Available Between ".date('d/m/Y',strtotime($settings['room_block_start_date']))." to ".date('d/m/Y',strtotime($settings['room_block_end_date']))."  ";
                            $CI->session->set_flashdata('error', $block_message);
                            redirect('');

                        }
                                        $CI->db->where('O.room_type_id',$room_type_id);
                                        $CI->db->where('R.date',$date);
                                        $CI->db->select('R.*,');
                                        $CI->db->join('orders O', 'O.id = R.order_id', 'LEFT');
                        $orders     =   $CI->db->get('rel_orders_prices R')->result_array();
                        //echo '<pre>'; print_r($orders);die;
                        //echo $total_rooms;die; 
                        if($total_rooms > 0){
                            //echo count($orders);die;
                            if(count($orders) >= $total_rooms){
                                $CI->session->unset_userdata('booking_data');
                                $CI->session->unset_userdata('coupon_data');
                                $CI->session->set_flashdata('error', "Sorry.. This Dates Between Rooms Not Available Please Try With Another Date Or Room");
                                redirect('front/book/index'.$query);
                            }else{
                                continue;   // continue loop
                            }
                        }else{
                                $CI->session->unset_userdata('booking_data');
                                $CI->session->unset_userdata('coupon_data');
                                $CI->session->set_flashdata('error', "Sorry.. This Dates Between Rooms Not Available Please Try With Another Date Or Room");
                                redirect('front/book/index'.$query);
                        }
                    }

    return;
}

function check_availability_ajax($check_in,$check_out,$adults,$kids,$room_type_id){
                $query      =   '?date_from='.$check_in.'&date_to='.$check_out.'&adults='.$adults.'&kids='.$kids.'&room_type='; 
                $CI =& get_instance();
                if($check_in==$check_out){
                    $check_out  =   date('Y-m-d', strtotime($check_out.'+ 1 day'));
                }
                                        $CI->db->where('id',1);
                    $settings   =   $CI->db->get('settings')->row_array();

                                        $CI->db->where('id',$room_type_id);
                                        $CI->db->select('room_types.*,base_price as price');
                    $room_type  =   $CI->db->get('room_types')->row_array();
                    //echo '<pre>'; print_r($room_type);die;

                                        $CI->db->where('room_type_id',$room_type_id);
                                        $CI->db->select('rooms.*,count(room_no) as total_rooms');
                    $rooms      =   $CI->db->get('rooms')->row_array();
                    $total_rooms    =   $rooms['total_rooms'];
                    //echo '<pre>'; print_r($rooms);die;
                    $begin = new DateTime($check_in);
                    $end = new DateTime($check_out);

                    $interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day');
                    $period = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end);

                    foreach($period as $dt){
                        $date       =    $dt->format( "Y-m-d" );    
                        $dayno      =    $dt->format( "N" );
                        $day        =    $dt->format( "D" );
                        $day        =   strtolower($day);

                        if($date >= $settings['room_block_start_date'] && $date <=$settings['room_block_end_date'])
                        {
                            $block_message  =   "Sorry.. No Room Available Between ".date('d/m/Y',strtotime($settings['room_block_start_date']))." to ".date('d/m/Y',strtotime($settings['room_block_end_date']))."  ";
                            return $block_message;


                        }

                                        $CI->db->where('O.room_type_id',$room_type_id);
                                        $CI->db->where('R.date',$date);
                                        $CI->db->select('R.*,');
                                        $CI->db->join('orders O', 'O.id = R.order_id', 'LEFT');
                    $orders     =   $CI->db->get('rel_orders_prices R')->result_array();
                        //echo $total_rooms;die; 
                        if($total_rooms > 0){
                            if(count($orders) > $total_rooms){
                                $CI->session->unset_userdata('booking_data');
                                $CI->session->unset_userdata('coupon_data');
                                return 'Sorry.. This Dates Between Rooms Not Available Please Try With Another Date Or Room';
                            }else{
                                continue;   // continue loop
                            }
                        }else{
                                $CI->session->unset_userdata('booking_data');
                                $CI->session->unset_userdata('coupon_data');
                                return 'Sorry.. This Dates Between Rooms Not Available Please Try With Another Date Or Room';
                        }
                    }

    return 1;
}
```

Here is my Book.php controller code where I use that functions:

```
function index()
{
    //echo '<pre>'; print_r($_GET);
    //check availbilty
    //get_invoice_number();
    $this->session->unset_userdata('booking_data');
    $this->session->unset_userdata('coupon_data');
    $data['page_title']     = lang('make_reservation');
    $data['meta_description']   =   $this->setting->meta_description;
    $data['meta_keywords']      =   $this->setting->meta_keywords;  
    $data['banners']        = $this->homepage_model->get_banners();
    $data['testimonials']   = $this->homepage_model->get_testimonials();    // get 6 testimonials
    $data['room_types']     = $this->homepage_model->get_room_types_all();
    $data['taxes']          = $this->homepage_model->get_taxes();
        if(!empty($_GET['room_type'])){
            $data['services']           = $this->homepage_model->get_paid_services($_GET['room_type']);
        }
        //echo '<pre>'; print_r($data['services']);
    if(empty($_GET['room_type'])){
        $this->render('book/room_types', $data);        
    }else{
        check_availability($_GET['date_from'],$_GET['date_to'],$_GET['adults'],$_GET['kids'],$_GET['room_type']);

        $data['room_type']      = $this->homepage_model->get_room_type($_GET['room_type']);

        $this->render('book/view', $data);      
    }


}
```

Comment: Show us the code where the actual error occurred.

Comment: Line 691? @shahsani

Comment: Lol, and where is Line 691? anyhow you have to specify `GROUP BY` expression in the query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are facing this problem because of the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` option in the MYSQL so kindly set,

`SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));`

to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

SQL query including aggregate functions like `COUNT()` or `SUM()` etc. always have a `GROUP BY` clause in it. Which specifies the other non-grouped columns in the final resultset.

In you query the following remarks are noted:

1. You have specified `rooms.*` which is not recommended while grouping.
2. You may mention specific columns while grouping, and specify those columns in the `GROUP BY` clause too.

For example,

```
SELECT
    Count(product_tb.product_id),
    product_tb.`name`,
    product_tb.details
FROM
    `product_tb`
WHERE
product_tb.product_id = 1
GROUP BY
    product_tb.`name`,
    product_tb.details
```

Comment: I've change my question and add some functions